# "Launch the Farm Configuration Wizard" link missing for Farm Admin

Tags: 2013, central-administration, configuration-wizard

I have two service accounts as below.

Setup - This is part of local admin and I used this to install SharePoint
Farm - This is my farm administrator and it is not part of local admin

When I log in as "Setup" then I can see the link "Launch the Farm Configuration Wizard" under "Farm Configuration" but when I log in as "Farm" then I don't see the link. Why?

Comment: Yeah this will work but why is it so? If I am farm admin then shouldn't I have all rights on that farm to perform any operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start Central Administration as Administrator (right-click -> Run as Administrator)

Not sure why this will help, but it has something to do with how Central Admin trims some links depending on if the IE process is running as local admin or not

Comment: Also - its not available for single server installations - you have to use psconfig.exe instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248514/missing-farm-configuration-wizard

Comment: No, I have SPF 2013 standalone with latest CU's - and after Robert's hint it works(IE 10)

Comment: I did the same, but still I am unable to view the link. Any other suggestions?